# upower.service fails to start ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, power-management, services

I just upgraded from Ubuntu lxde 18.04 to Ubuntu lxqt 20.04, and I encounter some problems with upower.service not starting properly (at boot-up and when I try to launch the service with `sudo service start upower`).

```
journalctl -xe -u upower 

avril 02 16:19:18  upowerd[14136]:
g_dbus_proxy_get_connection: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)'
failed avril 02 16:19:18  upowerd[14136]:
g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION
(connection)' failed avril 02 16:19:18  upowerd[14136]:
g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)'
failed avril 02 16:19:18  upowerd[14136]: Could not
acquire inhibitor lock: Unknown reason avril 02 16:19:18
 upowerd[14136]: g_dbus_proxy_get_connection: assertion
'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed avril 02 16:19:18 
upowerd[14136]: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion
'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed avril 02 16:19:18
 systemd[1]: upower.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit upower.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

If I launch the daemon manually as root with:

```
sudo /usr/lib/upower/upowerd --verbose &
```

It works fine.

And I can then start `xfce4-power-manager` or `lxqt-powermanagement` as non-root.

I have not changed how the service is defined :

File : `/lib/systemd/system/upower.service`

```
[Unit] Description=Daemon for power management
Documentation=man:upowerd(8)

[Service] Type=dbus BusName=org.freedesktop.UPower
ExecStart=/usr/lib/upower/upowerd Restart=on-failure

# Filesystem lockdown ProtectSystem=strict
# Needed by keyboard backlight support ProtectKernelTunables=false ProtectControlGroups=true ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/upower
StateDirectory=upower ProtectHome=true PrivateTmp=true

# Network
# PrivateNetwork=true would block udev's netlink socket IPAddressDeny=any RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLINK

# Execute Mappings MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true

# Modules ProtectKernelModules=true

# Real-time RestrictRealtime=true

# Privilege escalation NoNewPrivileges=true

# Capabilities CapabilityBoundingSet=

# System call interfaces LockPersonality=yes SystemCallArchitectures=native SystemCallFilter=@system-service
SystemCallFilter=ioprio_get

# Namespaces PrivateUsers=yes RestrictNamespaces=yes

# Locked memory LimitMEMLOCK=0

[Install] WantedBy=graphical.target
```

My Ubuntu kernel version:

```
uname - a

4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit (Thanks to @David I realized something must have gone wrong during the update process, I did `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04` and `sudo grub-set-default 0` and `sudo update-grub`) and now I'm running on a recent kernel, but it still doesn't work.
:

```
uname - a

Linux  5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:43:35
UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can you please advise on how to get upower to start properly as a service ? Thanks

Comment: Hello. If I read this correctly you have Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 4.15.0-96-generic This is a bit confusing can you please confirm. Also all the various fonts make it hard to read, does not help.

Comment: @David yes, I have I think successfully upgraded

Comment: This is why I am confused Ubuntu 20.04 comes with kernel 5.4 When first installed. How did you end up with this far lower kernel? The kernel you say you are running came with 18.04 Something is not right here.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have bigger problem than upower then. My lsb_release -a returns Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I'll try to see if I can still salvage it somehow.

Comment: @David I updated the grub (that had remained with a custom default-grub=saved) so that it boots to the new kernel and I'm now on 5.13 but unfortunately upower still doesn't start properly

Comment: If you read the Lubuntu 20.04 LTS release notes (eg. https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/) you'll have read "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" as the change from LXDE to LXQt created issues as per documentation.. I'd suggest a re-install  (Note: 20.04.3/.4 release notes didn't include that warning as Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was already EOL)